# ReactJS is not being able to map an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am the error bellow.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of
>   undefined

when trying to execute the map function below, where the link that simulates the API is http://www.mocky.io/v2/5db88c413b00004f0b35f1f1:

```
state = {
        name: 'Teste II', 
        produto: null,
        alternativas: null,
        atributos: null,
        loading_produto: true,
        loading_alternativas: true,
        loading_atributos: true,
        showPopup: false,
    };

    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );     
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5db88c413b00004f0b35f1f1";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({produto: data.suggestions[0], loading_produto: false})
        this.setState({alternativas: data.choices, loading_alternativas: false})
        this.setState({atributos: data.suggestions[0].attributes, loading_atributos: false})
        console.log(this.state.produto.product_data.title);
    }

render() {

    const lista_alternativas = this.state.alternativas;
    const lista_atributos = this.state.atributos;


        if(!this.state.loading_atributos){

            this.atributos = lista_atributos.map((description, key) => {
                console.log('chegou aqui');

                return  <li key={description.id}>{description.description}</li>
            });
        }

return (
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the response of that URL, you're setting the state value "atributos" to data.suggestions[0].attributes (which doesn't exist).

You might want to change that to data.suggestions[0].product_data.attributes.

More specifically, change your componentDidMount function to this:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5db88c413b00004f0b35f1f1";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({produto: data.suggestions[0], loading_produto: false})
    this.setState({alternativas: data.choices, loading_alternativas: false})
    this.setState({atributos: data.suggestions[0].product_data.attributes, loading_atributos: false})
    console.log(this.state.produto.product_data.title);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the initial state of atributos to an empty array instead of null:

```
state = {
        name: 'Teste II', 
        produto: null,
        alternativas: null,
        atributos: [],
        loading_produto: true,
        loading_alternativas: true,
        loading_atributos: true,
        showPopup: false,
    };
```